# Calling a method X amount of times

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am looking for a way to run code X times, using the same piece of code.

Say I wanted to repeat the code:

```
NSLog(@"repeat");
```

numberX amount of times:

```
int numberX;
```

without having to change any code depending on the value of numberX.

How would this be done? If you need any more explaining, or an explanation of what I am trying to achieve with the code, please comment.

Comment: you should really read some basic programming literature, look at my response below for a good start with objective-c!

Comment: Atleast learn basics before posting such questions.. :)

Comment: @MJB I have programmed in objective-c for many years and I still don't know the answer of this question. The for-loop is not an answer, its a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i< numberX; i++) {
// the code you want to repeat

}
```

Answer (score 2):

user a for loop:

```
for(int x = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_TIMES; x++){
  NSLog(@"repeat");
}
```

and make **sure** you read [this Objective-C Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop! Create your method:

```
(void) aMethod{
NSLog(@"Repeat");
}
```

Use method in the original method in a for loop:

```
int numberX = 123456789;
for(int loopInt = numberX; loopInt >= 0){
aMethod;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to run the tasks synchronously, you can insert your tasks into a Serial Dispatch Queue.  It is a FIFO.